# CSS Animation behind a menu and tag line

Tags: html, css-transitions, css-animations

I am working on programming some animation for client. They would like the company name to rise out from behind the line below or possibly an image below. The ultimate goal it to get to the logo on [this page](http://ndr-ae.com/) without using flash.

I have an animation that I have been working on here: http://inventivewebdesign.com/ndr/

My problem is that it shows up in front of the naviagation menu and the tagline below it. I'd like it to go behind. I have tried changing the z-index but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <a class="home-link" href="http://inventivewebdesign.com/ndr/" title="NDR" rel="home">
                <div id="title-animation" class="slideUp"><h1 class="site-title">NDR</h1></div>
            </a>
                <h2 class="site-description">Architecture &bull; Engineering</h2>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://inventivewebdesign.com/ndr/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
        </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

CSS:

```
.site-header .home-link {
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.site-header .site-description{
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
}


.site-title {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}    

/* ANIMATIONS */

#title-animation{
    /*background-color: #fe5652;*/
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slideUp{
    animation-name: slideUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;    

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

    visibility: visible !important;         
}

@keyframes slideUp {
    0%      {transform: translateY(100%);}
    80%     {transform: translateY(-4%);}
    95%     {transform: translateY(2%);}            
    100%    {transform: translateY(0%);}    
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
    0%      {-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);}
    80%     {-webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);}
    95%     {-webkit-transform: translateY(2%);}            
    100%    {-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index wont work if you don't specify a position.

Adding

> position:relative

, or

> position:absolute

will sort out the z-index straight away

so...

```
.site-header .home-link {
    position:relative;
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.site-header .site-description{
    position:relative;
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
}


.site-title {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```